# How do I globally override variant, color, style, etc. for Material-UI components?

Tags: material-ui

Instead of doing this everywhere:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary" 
  style={{textTransform: "none"}}    
>
  Description
</Button>
```

I just want to write:

```
<Button>
  Description
</Button>
```

Can I use theme overrides to do this and what would that look like?

Note that I'm trying to override both Material-UI properties and CSS styles.  I want to do this globally (i.e. not using `withStyles()` stuff everywhere).

Or can this only be done by defining some kind of new `AppButton` component?

Currently using **material-ui 3.2.2**

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with global overrides for your theme. 
Documentation is here https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type

Doing it this way will still allow you override the variant on a per component basis as well.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Name of the component ⚛️
    MuiButton: {
      // The properties to apply
      variant: 'contained'
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate way to do this, without defining a new component.

Custom components can be awkward when used with Material-UI's [JSS](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/) styling solution with Typescript.  I've found it difficult to define `WithStyle` types when combining style types from the shared component and the thing using it.

Instead of defining components, it's possible to define sets of default properties that you then apply with the spread operator.

Define and export a standard set of shared props somewhere out in your app:

```
import {LinearProgressProps} from "@material-ui/core/LinearProgress";

export const linearProps: LinearProgressProps = {
  variant:"indeterminate",
  color:"primary",
  style:{height:"2px"},
};
```

Then use those props in your app:

```
<LinearProgress {...linearProps} />
```

This is then easy to override with custom properties, custom inline styles or JSS generated styles:

```
<LinearProgress {...linearProps} className={classes.customProgress}
  color="secondary" style={{...linearProps.style, width: "100%"}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this question, assuming there is no Material-UI way to do this, here's my custom button component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Button} from "@material-ui/core";
import {ButtonProps} from "@material-ui/core/Button";


export class AppButton extends React.Component<ButtonProps, {}>{
  render(){
    let {style, ...props} = this.props;
    return <Button {...props} variant="contained" color="primary"
      style={{...style, textTransform: "none"}}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </Button>
  }
}
AppButton.muiName = 'Button';
```